# Error on query that works with a single column of my DB

Tags: android, database, android-sqlite, android-room, dao

I am using Android Architecture Components with Room library. Basically I want to fetch results from two separated columns in two different queries. I'll be glad if someone can help or advice me how to systemize my entity, thank you.

```
@Entity(tableName = "note_table")
public class Note {

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "id_col")
    private int id;

    @Ignore
    @ColumnInfo(name = "checks_col")       
    private ArrayList<Checks> checks = new ArrayList<>();

    @ColumnInfo(name = "res_col")
    private String result;

    public Note(String result, ArrayList<Checks> checks) {
        this.checks = checks;
        this.result = result;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {this.id = id;}
    public int getId() {return id;}
    public void setResult(String result){this.result = result;}
    public String getResult() {return result;}
    public void setChecks(ArrayList<Checks> checks){this.checks = checks;}
    @TypeConverters({Converters.class})
    public ArrayList<Checks> getChecks() {return checks;}

}
```

```
@Dao
public interface NoteDao {

    @Insert
    void insert(Note note);

    @Update
    void update(Note note);

    @Delete
    void delete(Note note);

    @Query("DELETE FROM note_table")
    void deleteAllNotes();

    @Query("SELECT * FROM note_table")
    LiveData<List<Note>> getAllNotes();

    @Query("SELECT res_col FROM note_table ORDER BY res_col DESC LIMIT 1 ") // <-- this is my try //
    LiveData<Note> getResultNote();

}
```

Error is given below:

```
The columns returned by the query does not have the fields [id] . Even though they are annotated as non-null or primitive. Columns returned by the query: [res_col]
```

Warning message is given below:

```
Note has some fields [id_col] which are not returned by the query. If they are not supposed to be read from the result, you can mark them with @Ignore annotation. You can suppress this warning by annotating the method with @SuppressWarnings(RoomWarnings.CURSOR_MISMATCH). Columns returned by the query: res_col. Fields in Note: id_col, res_col.
```

Comment: Just add id to the constructor of Note entity class and since id is `autoGenerate = true` pass null when inserting data.

Comment: Same , something is wrong with query.

Comment: Can you explain? what is the desired output more clearly?

Comment: According to your query, do you want only the string(res_col)?

Comment: Simply i want to get the last saved result in current column ,which is res_col

Answer (score 0):

```
LiveData<Note> getResultNote();
```

Wants to return a **Note** object, as some columns are annotated or implied as not null *(i.e. `private int id;` as **int** is a Java primative then it cannot be null)* then a **Note** cannot be built for the **String** that is to be returned by the query.

You want `getResultNote()` to return a **String** not a **Note**.

Alternately use `SELECT * .....` instead of `SELECT res_col ......` to return the Note and then get the String from the **Note**.